# Discrepancy between diagram and equations of GRU?

Tags: gated-recurrent-unit

While I was reading the blog of Colah,
In the diagram we can clearly see that z<sub>t</sub> is going to 
<sup>~</sup>h<sub>t</sub> and not r<sub>t</sub>
But the equations say otherwise. Isn’t this supposed to be z<sub>t</sub>*h<sub>t-1</sub> And not r<sub>t</sub>*h<sub>t-1</sub>.
Please correct me if I’m wrong.

[image: GRU]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this is somehow old, however, if you still haven't figured it out and care, or for any other person who would end up here, the answer is that the figure and equations are consistent. Note that, the operator (x) in the diagram (the pink circle with an X in it) is the Hadamard product, which is an element-wise multiplication between two tensors of the same size. In the equations, this operator is illustrated by `*` (usually it is represented by a circle and a dot at its center). `~h_t` is the output of the tanh operator. The tanh operator receives a linear combination of the input at time `t`, `x_t`, and the result of the Hadamard product between `r_t` and `h_{t-1}`. Note that `r_t` should have already been updated by passing the linear combination of `x_t` and `h_{t-1}` through a sigmoid. I hope the reset is clear.